# Strange behaviour of NumberFormat Java

Tags: java, validation, parsing, number-formatting

I have  the following code to parse a String variable called str.

```
NumberFormat formatter = NumberFormat.getInstance();
Number number = formatter.parse(str);
```

I want to catch the Exception thrown when str is not a number just to validate it. The problem I have is that it does't always throws the ParseException expected. When the String str starts with a number but then are characters it seems to get a the first characters of the String and parse them as a number.

For example:

- if str="a10" then is thrown a ParseException
- if str="10a" then no exception thrown and number=10

I cannot use Double.parseDouble(str) because str can have commas and points like 1,000.98 and this format is not understood by this method.

Why is this happening? Can I validate it in any other way? 
Thanks

Comment: I didn't mean that the behaviour of NumberFormat was wrong, but I had misunderstood the API. I thought position was to indicate until which character I wanted to parse the String. Now I understand why it's designed in this way. Thanks for all your anwers.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The behaviour is not strange, it's as designed

> Parses text from the beginning of the given string to produce a number. The method may not use the entire text of the given string.

You may use the position-aware parsing method like this:

```
public static double parse(String str) throws ParseException {
  NumberFormat formatter = NumberFormat.getInstance();
  ParsePosition position = new ParsePosition(0);
  Number number = formatter.parse(str, position);
  if (position.getIndex() != str.length()) {
    throw new ParseException("failed to parse entire string: " + str, position.getIndex());
  }
  return number.doubleValue();
}
```

Comment: Useful to me: use `setParseIntegerOnly(true)` to throw an exception if you find a Float when expecting a Integer

Answer (score 6):

If you look at the [API](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/NumberFormat.html#parse(java.lang.String)), it clearly says:

> Parses text from the beginning of the
>   given string to produce a number. The
>   method may not use the entire text of
>   the given string.

If you want to see how far the parser parsed, you can use the [other position-aware  method](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/NumberFormat.html#parse(java.lang.String,%20java.text.ParsePosition)). This way you can check if you have any trailing chars. You could also check the whole string for alphanumeric chars using for instance common langs [isAlpha](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html#isAlpha(java.lang.String)).

Comment: Sorry sfussenegger, didn't see your post before I updated with the position aware method.

Comment: @disown most likely because you've been faster than me ;)